# Insert Data in seconds between 30 minutes time interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to divide my time interval from the start time to end time.

The elapsed time should be divided across 30 minute time intervals so that for this input

```
08:05:13   12:09:49
```

I should get following output.

[image]

Comment: Hi, First of all welcome to the site. I tried rewording your question a bit so it becomes clearer. If I deviated from your intent let me know or roll it back yourself. Also, If you have a way to post your expected output as text, please do so instead of a screen shot. There are ways to [create tables here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83009/do-you-know-any-online-tool-that-creates-ascii-tables-for-proper-use-on-stack-ex)

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this involves creating a table of 48 daily half-hour period start times:

```
CREATE TABLE #HalfHours
(
    IntervalFrom time(3) PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT #HalfHours
    (IntervalFrom)
SELECT 
    DATEADD
    (
        MINUTE, 
        30 * (SV.number - 1), 
        CONVERT(time(3), '00:00:00.000')
    )
FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS SV
WHERE
    SV.[type] = N'P'
    AND SV.number BETWEEN 1 AND 48;
```

We can then use a query like the following:

```
-- The specified times
DECLARE
    @Start time(3) = '08:05:13',
    @End time(3) = '12:09:49';

SELECT
    HH.IntervalFrom,
    IntervalTo = CA.IntervalEnd,
    Elapsed =
        CASE
            -- Current period fully covered
            WHEN @Start <= HH.IntervalFrom AND @End >= CA.IntervalEnd 
                THEN 1800
            -- @Start within current period, @End not
            WHEN @Start > HH.IntervalFrom AND @End >= CA.IntervalEnd
                THEN 1800 - DATEDIFF(SECOND, HH.IntervalFrom, @Start)
            -- @End within current period, @Start not
            WHEN @Start <= HH.IntervalFrom AND @End < CA.IntervalEnd
                THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, HH.IntervalFrom, @End)
            -- @Start and @End both within current period
            ELSE DATEDIFF(SECOND, @Start, @End)
        END
FROM #HalfHours AS HH
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, HH.IntervalFrom))) AS CA (IntervalEnd)
WHERE
    @Start < @End
    AND HH.IntervalFrom < @End
    AND HH.IntervalFrom >= 
        CASE 
            WHEN @Start < CONVERT(time(3), '00:00:30.000') 
                THEN CONVERT(time(3), '00:00:00.000') 
            ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, @Start)
        END;
```

[image: Results]

[image: Execution plan]

This can be generalized quite easily in case the input is more than a single pair of start/end times.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of examples better that mine (above) :-)

```
    DECLARE @hi TIME(0) = '08:00';
    DECLARE @hf TIME(0) = '12:09';
    DECLARE @ha TIME(0) = '08:00';
    DECLARE @MinutesToAdd INT = 30;

    DECLARE @tbEvents TABLE (
       id  INT IDENTITY,
       Hour1   TIME,
       Hour2   TIME
   )


  WHILE CONVERT(time(0), @ha) <= CONVERT(time(0), @hf)
  BEGIN

     INSERT INTO @tbEvents(Hour1,Hour2)
     VALUES  (
       @ha,
       (SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, @MinutesToAdd, @ha))
       )

    SET  @ha= DATEADD(MINUTE, @MinutesToAdd, @ha)
  END

  SELECT * FROM @tbEvents
```